# performSegueWithIdentifier doesn't work in a different ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have the following storyboard: [Main Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GAku.png)

In it, several custom View Controllers are programmatically embedded in the Scroll View. In one of them, a button is present and should trigger a segue to show the "hey" screen.

I have then wrote the following code:

```
@IBAction func addNewDateButtonDidTouched(sender :AnyObject) {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let storyboardInit = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainview")
    storyboardInit.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNewDate", sender: self)
}
```

This `@IBAction` seems to reload the inital view controller and perform the segue correclty (Xcode doesn't return any error). But the "hey" screen doesn't show up and its `viewDidLoad()` doesn't load.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling

```
storyboardInit.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNewDate", sender: self)
```

try

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNewDate", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `storyboardInit` in your code will instantiate a `UIViewController` that has an identifier "`mainview`".
But this `UIViewController` hasn't been added to the screen, when you're asking the controller to perform a segue.

So, I wouldn't do that. What I would do, to segue to the hey screen is either :

1. Create a segue from the current controller and just do this in the code : `self.performSegueWithIdentifier`
2. Instantiate the hey controller like this : `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, and then just do the `self.presentViewController`

So, to transition to a new controller, you have to start from the current controller.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your viewcontroller hierarchy correctly...

since the viewcontroller that contains the button to trigger the segue is a childviewcontroller of the viewcontroller that has the segue setup in storyboard i think you have to call `presentingViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNewDate", sender: self)`.